# Python, Abstracting a class best practice

Tags: class, serial-port, echo, microcontroller, abstraction

first question here on stack!

I have a need to create an abstraction layer between the Pyserial module and calls made to it from other modules. In short, the script will be sending commands to a device, but the method in which it sends those strings could either be via a serial port, or echo'd out a TTY line. The vast majority of the python code to control the device is rather mature and works great, but at this point we will be introducing another device type with the same features, just minus the serial port control.

For one device I  do the following...

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=1)
ser.write('command to microcontroller')
ser.close()
```

For the new device, since it's lacking a serial port I do the following...

```
import os
str = 'command to microcontroller'
a = 'echo' + " '" + str + "' " + "> " + '/dev/ttymxc0'
os.system(a)
```

I have a working process to handle this at the moment, but it seems very wasteful. I basically import serial in a module (the snippets above are from this module) and make all of my calls to communicate with the micro to this module, to determine if it should go out a serial port or echo out a tty line. It seems like I'm basically rewriting functions for every part of the Serial module (ser.write, ser.close, ser.DTR etc) and creating if statements based on device type.

My question is, would a class in this example be less wasteful in terms of function and lines of code, or is it splitting hairs?

Thanks!